# Reactivate automatic scroll in fullpage.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

I'm looking for a little help!

I am using Alvaro Trigo's Fullpage.js for a Wordpress site I'm developing.

On the Homepage, I have each section scrolling automatically every 5000ms.

This feature is currently overridden if the user decides to navigate each section using the mouse.

The client has requested that the automatic scroll be reactivated if the user is inactive (ie. not manually scrolling) for 5000ms.

[Here is the work in progress](http://rankindev.co.uk/).

Thank you in advance — Any help will be much appreciated! Please let me know if you need any more information.

Answer (score 0):

[Example online](http://jsfiddle.net/97tbk/945/)

Try this:

```
var myIntervalId;
var auto = true;

$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    sectionsColor: ['yellow', 'orange', '#C0C0C0', '#ADD8E6'],
    continuousVertical: true,

    afterLoad: function (anchorLink, index){
        //for any section
        if(typeof myIntervalId === 'undefined' || !auto){
          clearInterval(myIntervalId);
          myIntervalId = setInterval(function() {
              $.fn.fullpage.moveSectionDown();
          }, 1000);
        }
    }
});




addMouseWheelHandler();

function MouseWheelHandler() {
    clearInterval(myIntervalId);
    auto = false;
}

function addMouseWheelHandler() {
    if (document.addEventListener) {
        document.addEventListener('mousewheel', MouseWheelHandler, false); //IE9, Chrome, Safari, Oper
        document.addEventListener('wheel', MouseWheelHandler, false); //Firefox
    } else {
        document.attachEvent('onmousewheel', MouseWheelHandler); //IE 6/7/8
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Alvaro – Thanks for coming back so quick. I might not have explained this correctly...

I need the automatic scroll to reactivate after the user has stopped it with the mousewheel and then been inactive for 5 seconds. In your JSFiddle, the mousewheel stops the automatic scroll but doesn't reactivate.

Thanks in advance and sorry for the miscommunication.

evan.

Comment: @Evan the example is reactivating the scroll whenever the user stops it. Review it again. You can test it scrolling up. It will get activated again after 1 second. (just change it to 5 in your case)

Comment: Sorry, it's not working for me :( I've tried it in Safari, Firefox and Chrome. Am I able to show you a screen capture somehow?

Comment: @Evan even if you can not see the jsfiddle example, I posted the whole code, which should be enough provided that I posted a similar code the other day with a working example. I'm sorry but I can not do more for you.